# CSS not rendering in Angular 6 with Custom Webpack Config

Tags: angular, webpack

UPDATE 2: 
I think that I have narrowed down the issue to the the use of the different loaders for the css property in `webpack.config.json`.

I am not really sure if these are configured correctly.

```
{ test: /\.(css)$/, use:['raw-loader','iso-morphic-style-loader','css-loader'] }
```

UPDATE:
Just want to mention that this issue only occurs when I package the application and deploy it.  When I use `ng serve` CSS renders fine.

Also thought it might be useful to include the exact command I'm running when building the application:
`webpack --mode=development`

We are using a custom webpack configuration with angular and deploying the built files to a tomcat instance.

For some reason the CSS is not rendering, and it appears the style tags are filled with JS instead of CSS styles which I am not sure is supposed to be what happens.  Most of the styling is located in the root CSS file in `src/styles.css`.  But when you visit `index.html` no styles get loaded.

This is what 
`webpack.config.js` looks like

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ScriptExtPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
const { AngularCompilerPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');

module.exports = function () {
    return {
        entry: {
            main: './src/main.ts',
            polyfills: './src/polyfills.ts',
            styles: "./src/styles.css"
        },
        output: {
            path: __dirname + '/dist',
            filename: '[name].js'
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
        },

        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, loader: '@ngtools/webpack'},
                { test: /\.(html)$/, use: 'html-loader' },
                // Use iso-morphic-style-loader instead of style-loader to avoid "ERROR in window is not defined."
                { test: /\.(css)$/, use:['raw-loader','iso-morphic-style-loader','css-loader'] }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets'}
            ]),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: __dirname + '/src/index.html',
                output: __dirname + '/dist',
                inject: 'head'
            }),

            new ScriptExtPlugin({
                defaultAttribute: 'defer'
            }),

            new AngularCompilerPlugin({
               tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
               entryModule: './src/app/app.module#AppModule',
               sourceMap: true
            })

        ]
    };
}
```

and here is what is getting rendered in the `<head>` of the `index.html` page

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ui</title>
  <base href="/InternalGUI-InstallationGUI/v2/dist/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js" defer=""></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js" defer=""></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js" defer=""></script><style>//[_ngcontent-c0]   style-loader[_ngcontent-c0]:   Adds[_ngcontent-c0]   some[_ngcontent-c0]   css[_ngcontent-c0]   to[_ngcontent-c0]   the[_ngcontent-c0]   DOM[_ngcontent-c0]   by[_ngcontent-c0]   adding[_ngcontent-c0]   a[_ngcontent-c0]   <style[_ngcontent-c0] > tag

//[_ngcontent-c0]   load[_ngcontent-c0]   the[_ngcontent-c0]   styles
var[_ngcontent-c0]   content[_ngcontent-c0]   =[_ngcontent-c0]   require("!!../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./app.component.css")[_ngcontent-c0];
if(typeof[_ngcontent-c0]   content[_ngcontent-c0]   ===[_ngcontent-c0]   'string')[_ngcontent-c0]   content[_ngcontent-c0]   =[_ngcontent-c0]   [[module.id[_ngcontent-c0], content[_ngcontent-c0], '']][_ngcontent-c0];
//[_ngcontent-c0]   Prepare[_ngcontent-c0]   cssTransformation
var[_ngcontent-c0]   transform[_ngcontent-c0];

var[_ngcontent-c0]   options[_ngcontent-c0]   =[_ngcontent-c0] {}
options.transform[_ngcontent-c0]   =[_ngcontent-c0]   transform
//[_ngcontent-c0]   add[_ngcontent-c0]   the[_ngcontent-c0]   styles[_ngcontent-c0]   to[_ngcontent-c0]   the[_ngcontent-c0]   DOM
var[_ngcontent-c0]   update[_ngcontent-c0]   =[_ngcontent-c0]   require("!../../node_modules/iso-morphic-style-loader/lib/addUniversalStyles.js")(content[_ngcontent-c0], options)[_ngcontent-c0];
if(content.locals)[_ngcontent-c0]   module.exports[_ngcontent-c0]   =[_ngcontent-c0]   content.locals[_ngcontent-c0];
module.exports.__universal__[_ngcontent-c0]   =[_ngcontent-c0]   update.__universal__[_ngcontent-c0];
//[_ngcontent-c0]   Hot[_ngcontent-c0]   Module[_ngcontent-c0]   Replacement
if(module.hot[_ngcontent-c0]   &&[_ngcontent-c0]   typeof[_ngcontent-c0]   window[_ngcontent-c0]   ===[_ngcontent-c0]   'object'[_ngcontent-c0]   &&[_ngcontent-c0]   window.document)[_ngcontent-c0] {
    // When the styles change, update the <style> tags
    if(!content.locals) {
        module.hot.accept("!!../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./app.component.css", function() {
            var newContent = require("!!../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./app.component.css");
            if(typeof newContent === 'string') newContent = [[module.id, newContent, '']];
            update(newContent);
        });
    }
    // When the module is disposed, remove the <style> tags
    module.hot.dispose(function() { update(); });
}</style><style>//[_ngcontent-c1]   style-loader[_ngcontent-c1]:   Adds[_ngcontent-c1]   some[_ngcontent-c1]   css[_ngcontent-c1]   to[_ngcontent-c1]   the[_ngcontent-c1]   DOM[_ngcontent-c1]   by[_ngcontent-c1]   adding[_ngcontent-c1]   a[_ngcontent-c1]   <style[_ngcontent-c1] > tag

//[_ngcontent-c1]   load[_ngcontent-c1]   the[_ngcontent-c1]   styles
var[_ngcontent-c1]   content[_ngcontent-c1]   =[_ngcontent-c1]   require("!!../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./footer.component.css")[_ngcontent-c1];
if(typeof[_ngcontent-c1]   content[_ngcontent-c1]   ===[_ngcontent-c1]   'string')[_ngcontent-c1]   content[_ngcontent-c1]   =[_ngcontent-c1]   [[module.id[_ngcontent-c1], content[_ngcontent-c1], '']][_ngcontent-c1];
//[_ngcontent-c1]   Prepare[_ngcontent-c1]   cssTransformation
var[_ngcontent-c1]   transform[_ngcontent-c1];

var[_ngcontent-c1]   options[_ngcontent-c1]   =[_ngcontent-c1] {}
options.transform[_ngcontent-c1]   =[_ngcontent-c1]   transform
//[_ngcontent-c1]   add[_ngcontent-c1]   the[_ngcontent-c1]   styles[_ngcontent-c1]   to[_ngcontent-c1]   the[_ngcontent-c1]   DOM
var[_ngcontent-c1]   update[_ngcontent-c1]   =[_ngcontent-c1]   require("!../../../node_modules/iso-morphic-style-loader/lib/addUniversalStyles.js")(content[_ngcontent-c1], options)[_ngcontent-c1];
if(content.locals)[_ngcontent-c1]   module.exports[_ngcontent-c1]   =[_ngcontent-c1]   content.locals[_ngcontent-c1];
module.exports.__universal__[_ngcontent-c1]   =[_ngcontent-c1]   update.__universal__[_ngcontent-c1];
//[_ngcontent-c1]   Hot[_ngcontent-c1]   Module[_ngcontent-c1]   Replacement
if(module.hot[_ngcontent-c1]   &&[_ngcontent-c1]   typeof[_ngcontent-c1]   window[_ngcontent-c1]   ===[_ngcontent-c1]   'object'[_ngcontent-c1]   &&[_ngcontent-c1]   window.document)[_ngcontent-c1] {
    // When the styles change, update the <style> tags
    if(!content.locals) {
        module.hot.accept("!!../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./footer.component.css", function() {
            var newContent = require("!!../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./footer.component.css");
            if(typeof newContent === 'string') newContent = [[module.id, newContent, '']];
            update(newContent);
        });
    }
    // When the module is disposed, remove the <style> tags
    module.hot.dispose(function() { update(); });
}</style><style>//[_ngcontent-c2]   style-loader[_ngcontent-c2]:   Adds[_ngcontent-c2]   some[_ngcontent-c2]   css[_ngcontent-c2]   to[_ngcontent-c2]   the[_ngcontent-c2]   DOM[_ngcontent-c2]   by[_ngcontent-c2]   adding[_ngcontent-c2]   a[_ngcontent-c2]   <style[_ngcontent-c2] > tag

//[_ngcontent-c2]   load[_ngcontent-c2]   the[_ngcontent-c2]   styles
var[_ngcontent-c2]   content[_ngcontent-c2]   =[_ngcontent-c2]   require("!!../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./start.component.css")[_ngcontent-c2];
if(typeof[_ngcontent-c2]   content[_ngcontent-c2]   ===[_ngcontent-c2]   'string')[_ngcontent-c2]   content[_ngcontent-c2]   =[_ngcontent-c2]   [[module.id[_ngcontent-c2], content[_ngcontent-c2], '']][_ngcontent-c2];
//[_ngcontent-c2]   Prepare[_ngcontent-c2]   cssTransformation
var[_ngcontent-c2]   transform[_ngcontent-c2];

var[_ngcontent-c2]   options[_ngcontent-c2]   =[_ngcontent-c2] {}
options.transform[_ngcontent-c2]   =[_ngcontent-c2]   transform
//[_ngcontent-c2]   add[_ngcontent-c2]   the[_ngcontent-c2]   styles[_ngcontent-c2]   to[_ngcontent-c2]   the[_ngcontent-c2]   DOM
var[_ngcontent-c2]   update[_ngcontent-c2]   =[_ngcontent-c2]   require("!../../../node_modules/iso-morphic-style-loader/lib/addUniversalStyles.js")(content[_ngcontent-c2], options)[_ngcontent-c2];
if(content.locals)[_ngcontent-c2]   module.exports[_ngcontent-c2]   =[_ngcontent-c2]   content.locals[_ngcontent-c2];
module.exports.__universal__[_ngcontent-c2]   =[_ngcontent-c2]   update.__universal__[_ngcontent-c2];
//[_ngcontent-c2]   Hot[_ngcontent-c2]   Module[_ngcontent-c2]   Replacement
if(module.hot[_ngcontent-c2]   &&[_ngcontent-c2]   typeof[_ngcontent-c2]   window[_ngcontent-c2]   ===[_ngcontent-c2]   'object'[_ngcontent-c2]   &&[_ngcontent-c2]   window.document)[_ngcontent-c2] {
    // When the styles change, update the <style> tags
    if(!content.locals) {
        module.hot.accept("!!../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./start.component.css", function() {
            var newContent = require("!!../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./start.component.css");
            if(typeof newContent === 'string') newContent = [[module.id, newContent, '']];
            update(newContent);
        });
    }
    // When the module is disposed, remove the <style> tags
    module.hot.dispose(function() { update(); });
}</style><style>//[_ngcontent-c3]   style-loader[_ngcontent-c3]:   Adds[_ngcontent-c3]   some[_ngcontent-c3]   css[_ngcontent-c3]   to[_ngcontent-c3]   the[_ngcontent-c3]   DOM[_ngcontent-c3]   by[_ngcontent-c3]   adding[_ngcontent-c3]   a[_ngcontent-c3]   <style[_ngcontent-c3] > tag

//[_ngcontent-c3]   load[_ngcontent-c3]   the[_ngcontent-c3]   styles
var[_ngcontent-c3]   content[_ngcontent-c3]   =[_ngcontent-c3]   require("!!../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./loading-spinner.component.css")[_ngcontent-c3];
if(typeof[_ngcontent-c3]   content[_ngcontent-c3]   ===[_ngcontent-c3]   'string')[_ngcontent-c3]   content[_ngcontent-c3]   =[_ngcontent-c3]   [[module.id[_ngcontent-c3], content[_ngcontent-c3], '']][_ngcontent-c3];
//[_ngcontent-c3]   Prepare[_ngcontent-c3]   cssTransformation
var[_ngcontent-c3]   transform[_ngcontent-c3];

var[_ngcontent-c3]   options[_ngcontent-c3]   =[_ngcontent-c3] {}
options.transform[_ngcontent-c3]   =[_ngcontent-c3]   transform
//[_ngcontent-c3]   add[_ngcontent-c3]   the[_ngcontent-c3]   styles[_ngcontent-c3]   to[_ngcontent-c3]   the[_ngcontent-c3]   DOM
var[_ngcontent-c3]   update[_ngcontent-c3]   =[_ngcontent-c3]   require("!../../../node_modules/iso-morphic-style-loader/lib/addUniversalStyles.js")(content[_ngcontent-c3], options)[_ngcontent-c3];
if(content.locals)[_ngcontent-c3]   module.exports[_ngcontent-c3]   =[_ngcontent-c3]   content.locals[_ngcontent-c3];
module.exports.__universal__[_ngcontent-c3]   =[_ngcontent-c3]   update.__universal__[_ngcontent-c3];
//[_ngcontent-c3]   Hot[_ngcontent-c3]   Module[_ngcontent-c3]   Replacement
if(module.hot[_ngcontent-c3]   &&[_ngcontent-c3]   typeof[_ngcontent-c3]   window[_ngcontent-c3]   ===[_ngcontent-c3]   'object'[_ngcontent-c3]   &&[_ngcontent-c3]   window.document)[_ngcontent-c3] {
    // When the styles change, update the <style> tags
    if(!content.locals) {
        module.hot.accept("!!../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./loading-spinner.component.css", function() {
            var newContent = require("!!../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./loading-spinner.component.css");
            if(typeof newContent === 'string') newContent = [[module.id, newContent, '']];
            update(newContent);
        });
    }
    // When the module is disposed, remove the <style> tags
    module.hot.dispose(function() { update(); });
}</style>
```

As you can see there's a bunch of javascript being put in these `<style>` tags, and I'm not sure if that's suppoed to happen or if there's an issue with the `webpack.config.js`.

Comment: Uh, no, you're not supposed to have javascript inside of style tags... :)

Comment: Figured! So it must be an issue with compilation during the build process.